# Using .val() in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why is `r` empty and `x` `undefined`?

html:

```
@{bool x = false;}
@foreach (var c in Model.Cleaner.TimeConfirmations.Where(l => l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() || l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()))
{
    x = true;
}
<span class="ifAvailable" data-confirmationchecker="@x" value="15">@x</span>
```

jquery:

```
if ($(".ifAvailable").val() == false) {
    var x = $(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationChecker');
    var r = $(".ifAvailable").val();
    alert(r);
    alert(x)
}
```

Comment: first of all `span` elements don't have an attribute `value`, second `confirmationChecker` != `confirmationchecker` (capital C in the first one)

Comment: do div elements have a value?

Comment: nope, this attribute only exists in `<button>, <option>, <input>, <li>, <meter>, <progress>, <param>`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! So You have to use data I guess

Comment: if($(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationchecker') == false){
           var x = $(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationchecker')
    } It still isn't working? even though x equals false it doesn't go into the if statement. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Your `@{ bool x = false; }` declares `x` in the scope of the `@{}` brackets. After those brackets, `x` is out of scope.

```
@{
        bool x = false;
        foreach (var c in Model.Cleaner.TimeConfirmations.Where(l => l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() || l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()))
        {
                x = true;
        }
}
```

The above code shows how to define and use x in the same scope.

`var r = $(".ifAvailable").val();` assuming the first matched element from the .ifAvailable class selector is that span, you're getting an empty string because the value attribute is not a standard attribute for span elements. jQuery is built to work against the standard, so your best bet here, if you continue to strangely insist on storing your client-side data in a span element, is to use data- attributes.

Comment: @N.Sch you'll have to post your own question with a MCVE
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve